# Intercepting and altering webview requests?

Tags: android, webview, httprequest

Is it possible to intercept complete requests made by webview in android?

I'm looking for something that would function to similar to

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("foo://")) {
            // magic
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However i would like to be able to get the entire http request and convert it to a string , and do the same for resource requests.